# Why do I always get timeout when trying to SSH from Ubuntu 22.04 into my Azure Linux virtual machine?

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, timeout, virtual-machine

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I bought a VM on Azure recently. Today, when I tried to log in using SSH, I failed to log in.

The command I am using is `ssh -i ~/.ssh/<KEY> user@public_IP_address`.

I am trying to use the SSH command from Ubuntu's bash terminal but also tried using PuTTy unsuccessfully earlier today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same in my environment got the same error like below:

[image]

This error usually occurs if network security group rules for the virtual machine port 22 (SSH) is not open for inbound traffic rule.

To check this use `telnet <vmpublicip> 22` it is not open connection to the host you need to update the NSG rules to allow your IP address to connect.

[image]

In virtual machine -> networking -> Add inbound port rule -> destination port add `22` like below:

[image]

Now, when I try to connect with SSH using `ssh user@public_IP_address` or `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@public_IP_address` it connected successfully like below.

[image]

If still error persists, check if the vm is in running status by navigating to boot diagnostics and serial log as below:

[image]

Check *uncomplicated firewall* status, firewall is blocking SSH connections and that rules are in active using below command:

```
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
```

```c
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Imran! This worked flawlessly.